# Does IntersectionObserver consider visible a div that is inside the viewport, but covered by another div?

Tags: javascript, viewport, intersection-observer

I'm having issues with Intersection Observer and don't really know what's the problem. So I've got a question as I'm curious:

- Let's imagine 2 divs A & B
- A & B are both 100vw by 100vh (full viewport)
- They're both moving together, same position
- B is above A and fully covers A

**Is Intersection Observer supposed to consider A as visible when it is inside the viewport? Even though it's fully covered?**

*By "visible" I mean isIntersecting = true*

Comment: Why not make a [mcve] which tests your hypothesis? Remember, intersection observer cares if something is intersecting.

Comment: _"Is Intersection Observer supposed to consider A as visible when it is inside the viewport? Even though it's fully covered?"_ supposed to? Who knows. Does it? Yes. — [Take a look here](https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/#calculate-intersection-rect-algo) it's the algorithm which determines the Intersection of a Target Element and the Root. It doesn't seem to care if anything is on top of it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox removed my comments to not add confusion and since I have to run. I'll leave here again the demo I used for testing in case someone wants to take over: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/63s029fd/

Comment: If it didn't, what should happen to B if A had an `opacity: 0.5`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As I'm not comfortable with Intersection Observer, I'm afraid of getting false positives or misleading results via my own attempts. Just wanted to get a confirmation from people who are used to Intersection Observer. Thanks! This is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.
To [compute the intersection of a Target Element and the Root](https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/#calculate-intersection-rect-algo) the UA only has to look at the *Target* element and the *Root* element (which is an ancestor node). Siblings don't matter, whether they cover the *Target* or not.

Determining if an element is covered by another element would bring some security considerations into the mix. For instance you could use it to determine if a certain image contains transparency or not, which in turn could help determining other privacy related contents. So while it's been [talked about before](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/issues/148), I'm not sure it's still on track.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido, I didn't stumble upon these connoisseur links, this is interesting.